# how to pass #VALX value of mscharts from one page to another using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i m working on MScharts in vb.net 2008. Can anyone help me how to pass the #VALX value from one page to another page. Thank in advance.

Can i know whether it is possible by using labelurl property as example

```
        <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" LabelUrl="abc.aspx?id={#VALX}">
        </asp:Series>
```

Comment: Plz anyone reply soon.. i m waiting for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub UpdateAttrib()       
    For Each series As Series In Chart1.Series       
        For pointIndex As Integer = 0 To series.Points.Count - 1  
            Dim toolTip As String = ""
            series.Points(pointIndex).Url = "abc.aspx?region="+ series.Points(pointIndex).AxisLabel
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Write the above code in `.cs` file and call below code in next page:

```
If Me.Page.Request("region") IsNot Nothing Then          
     region = DirectCast(Me.Page.Request("region"), String)      
End If
```